# Compact syntax to create tree structure in C#

Tags: c#, data-structures

I would like to create a somewhat complex tree structure in code, in a concise manner. Right now I'm using this (simplified):

```
var root = new Tree();
var c1 = root.Add("1");
var c2 = root.Add("2");
var c21 = c2.Add("2-1");
var c22 = c2.Add("2-2");
//...
```

Average node width is 4, tree height is about 5, so the above process is very tedious, not to mention poorly maintainable.

Let us assume the nodes are not accessed by name later. The tree/node classes can be adjusted as necessary. Performance can be disregarded. Creation via XML or similar is not possible (the node constructor is quite a bit more complicated in reality).

What I'm looking for is something like the following, but I'm not sure how this could be implemented in C#. In Java, this would be possible via anonymous classes, which cannot be used for this purpose in C#.

```
var root = new Tree() {
    Add("1");
    Add("2") {
        Add("2-1");
        Add("2-2");
    };
}
```

The best solution I could think of would use run-on declaration similar to the following, which I think is poorly maintainable:

```
// AddXxx returns the added node
var root = new Tree()
    .Add("1")
    .AddSibling("2")
        .Add("2-1")
        .AddSibling("2-2")
    .AddParent("3")
        .Add("3-1")
```

Or alternatively:

```
// Add now always adds a sibling, Children/Parent steps up/down in the hierarchy
var root = new Tree()
    .Children
    .Add("1")
    .Add("2")
        .Children
        .Add("2-1")
        .Add("2-2")
    .Parent
    .Add("3")
        .Children
        .Add("3-1")
```

Comment: C# does have anonymous classes.

Comment: Indeed right! But they cannot be used in this scenario. I will fix the question.

Comment: I'm not so sure creating using XML isn't possible- as long as your node classes can have parameterless constructors, you can just use the serialization feature to deserialize an XML document in a resource to whatever classes you want.

Comment: @Flynn1179 The issue is that the nodes require lambdas as arguments.

Comment: The C# design team is considering adding more "builder" syntactic sugars to C# 7; see the design discussions on the github site if you want to participate.

Answer (score 6):

I will do something like this:

```
public class Tree
{
    public string Name { get; private set; }
    public List<Tree> Trees { get; private set; }

    public Tree(string name)
    {
        this.Name = name;
        this.Trees = new List<Tree>();
    }

    public Tree(string name, params Tree[] nodes)
        : this(name)
    {
        if (nodes == null || !nodes.Any()) return;
        Trees.AddRange(nodes);
    }
}
```

Then use it like this:

```
var trees = new List<Tree>
{
    new Tree("1"),
    new Tree("2",
        new Tree("2-1"),
        new Tree("2-2",
            new Tree("2-2-1"),
            new Tree("2-2-1")
        )
    ),
    new Tree("3",
        new Tree("3-1")
    )
};
```

I was inspired to this by [XElement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/bb302741(v=vs.110).aspx) constructor which faciltate XML nodes creation with more readability. If you are working with XML then I recommend to use that class.

Comment: You can probably make it shorter using only strings and providing an implicit conversion operator.

Comment: But some readability will be lost. In the sample code in my answer only node "1", "2-1", "2-2-1", "2-2-2" will not need the constructor.

Answer (score 3):

You can use a [collection initializer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384062.aspx):

```
class Node : IEnumerable<Node> // implement interface to taste
{
    public Node(string name)
    {
        ...
    }

    public void Add(Node n)
    {
        ...
    }
}

var root = new Node("x")
{   // Each item in this {} is passed to Add
    new Node("y-1")
    {
        new Node("z-1"),
        new Node("z-2")
    },
    new Node("y-2")
};
```

Comment: I was not aware this technique could be used in UDT, this is perfect. According to MSDN, just the existence of an Add method suffices for this to work, it does not even have to be IEnumerable<>

Comment: @mafu Sadly MSDN is wrong; by the C# spec *The collection object to which a collection initializer is applied must be of a type that implements `System.Collections.IEnumerable` or a compile-time error occurs.* I think that's dumb myself, but having your node implement the interface will probably prove useful anyway.

Comment: @Rawling: The reasoning behind requiring `IEnumerable` is because we did research and discovered that there were only two kinds of types that had the vast majority of `Add` methods: mathematics classes and collection classes. They were most easily differentiated by the presence of `IEnumerable`.

Comment: @EricLippert Can't really argue with that!

Answer (score 1):

A conventional way to do this is with a collection initalizer.  I'm not a fan, because this means you need to implement an `Add` method, and *that* means you need to implement a mutable Tree interface, which is (IMHO) a hassle that makes many conventional tree algorithms unsafe.  (you could also implement freezable TreeBuilder, but that's just as much hassle).

I prefer to list all tree nodes at construction time, and with C# 6's `using static` you can do this quite cleanly.

Linqpad query:

```
void Main()
{
    Node("test",
        Node("kid"),
        Node("kid2",
            Node("grandchild")
        ),
        Node("kid3",
            Node("grandchild2"),
            Node("grandchild3")
        )
    )
    .ToString().Dump();
}

public static class Tree
{
    public static TreeNode<T> Node<T>(T val, params TreeNode<T>[] kids)
        => new TreeNode<T>(val, kids);
}

public struct TreeNode<T>
{
    public readonly T NodeValue;
    public readonly IReadOnlyList<TreeNode<T>> Kids;

    public TreeNode(T val, TreeNode<T>[] kids)
    {
        NodeValue = val;
        Kids = kids;
    }

    public override string ToString() 
        => $"\n{NodeValue}:{string.Join("", Kids).Replace("\n", "\n  ")}";
}
```

which prints:

```
test:
  kid:
  kid2:
    grandchild:
  kid3:
    grandchild2:
    grandchild3:
```

Note that reinterpreting an array as `IReadOnlyList` doesn't protect you from nasty callers that mutate params arrays after constructions, which is likely fine in a normal project, but possibly not so hot for a public api - YMMV.